# Call WCF service from iOS app

Tags: ios, wcf, download, afnetworking

****Background:****I have a "document repository" kind-of app.The iOS app calls a WCF service to download the document as well as to get its metadata(document name,document size,etc).There is also a .Net client used for uploading the documents.When I upload a document,I save it in the "AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory" by creating a separate folder for each document.So,effectively,the document is stored at "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Foo\bar\document.doc".

****The Problem:****when the iOS app  tries to download a document,it returns error 500 "Could not find a part of the path 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Foo\bar\document.doc'" However,it returns the metadata for the document(document name,document size,document location,etc.) correctly.

What should I do the make the app download the document?

Answer (score 1):

The error 500 was sending back from the server. So the problem is on server side. Are you sure that the path is correct? The uploaded document is on that directory?

Comment: I forgot to mention in the post,the WCF service and the application are hosted on separate servers.So,the service runs on Server1 and the application is hosted on Server2.The documents are uploaded on C:\ of Server2.When the iOS app calls the WCF service running on Server1,it looks for the document on c:\ here.The question is,how/where do I upload the document so that it is available to the iOS app?

Comment: Wait,Is the service on Server 1 and the document on Server 2? I dont' know what is the design of your system but for a "repository app" I  would use a server where to store the documents and the service. Then I  would create two methods wich give me the possiblity to upload and download documents. The app  would only calls these methods to retrive and store documents.